# Is it a convention to divide rate of reaction by stoichiometric coefficient?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, concentration

If we consider a reaction

$$ \ce{A + B -> 3 C} $$

The rate of reaction is given by

$$ R= -\dfrac{\Delta[A]}{\Delta t} = -\dfrac{\Delta[B]}{\Delta t} = \frac13\dfrac{\Delta[C]}{\Delta t} $$

I know we divide it by $3$ for equality, but we can also multiply $3$ in other two concentrations too, right? Then the result will be:

$$ R= -\dfrac{3\Delta[A]}{\Delta t} = -\dfrac{3\Delta[B]}{Δt}=\dfrac{\Delta[C]}{\Delta t}$$

So is it just a convention to divide instead of multiplication?

Comment: It is rather definition than convention. Also, search for related question on the site, there were several similar questions in recent history. // Take it as 1 mol of reaction formal operations, each taking 1 molecule A, 1 molecule B, forming 3 molecules C. So 1 mole of formal reactions consumes 1 mol A, 1 mol B, forming 3 mol C.

Comment: You may review also search results for [site:stackexchange.com reaction rate stoichiometric coefficient](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+reaction+rate+stoichiometric+coefficient)

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks, for replying. My doubt is now cleared

Comment: Also, think of a more "complicated" reaction, such as $\ce{5A + 3B -> 4C + 2D}$. It is not entirely clear and unambiguous how your "method with multiplication" could be used in such cases, while the "method with division" is completely straight-forward :)

Comment: As @Poutnik indicates, it is a definition. The value of the reaction velocity does not depend on which reactant or product you select.

Comment: @PAEP Yes. Maybe we divide them with respective coefficients to fit any reaction into the general framework of _what a reaction is_!